# For IE9, how do I make the curser on the email go to the end of the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, email

I have a button. This button has text and is used in **IE9**. When you click the button, it pops up an email. I gave the email a subject and body line. The problem is the cursor for the mouse is stuck on the beginning line of the body text when the email opens. I would like to have it several lines below where the customer can begin writing the problem they are having:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/zxz3utjy/

```
  <a href="mailto:d---------@mail.mil?subject=DCPAS/DMDC Helpdesk Request&body= Category: My Computer or Phone">
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you can control from the browser, because the cursor is owned by whatever e-mail client you're using (Outlook, Thunderbird, etc)

You'd have to have your site create and send the email instead of using a **mailto:** link.